# Problems with using the most recent version if Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, chatbot

I've been wanting to give tensorflow a shot for designing a chatbot. However, guides i've seen feel like they were all using an older version of Tensorflow because the one i'm using is the most recent one (2.16.1), which leads to some imports not being available in this version.

Badically, i'm using [this place as a short guide](https://handsonai.medium.com/developing-a-simple-chatbot-with-python-and-tensorflow-a-step-by-step-tutorial-0d35767e113b). They used the following imports:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense
```

The issue is I can't really do that. Even when I do tensorflow.python.keras, packages like preprocessing aren't available. What version of Tensorflow has all of those?

Comment: The modules exist, the import of them is just.. weird. [Same problem with solution](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/import-tensorflow-keras-shows-lint-error/17386/4). Personally, I just with `import tensorflow as tf` and import everything else in code with e.g. `tf.keras.xyz`. Gets a bit long, but works.